# Cluster of data for Statistical Analyse

Tags: probability-or-statistics

See this link in [Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Class.html).

I would like to run exactly this kind of analyze by Mathematica:

Are there any on with a link giving some examples or funtions I need to use?

thank you!

Comment: Do you know `Histogram` `GatherBy` and friends?

Comment: hello..yes the histogram workes perfectly. but for the documentation i would like to generate the corresponding table. i know all the data could be extracted by the histogram but i would like to do automatically. :)

Comment: Then use `Counts` or so. check the documentation out. Something like `CountsBy[data,Floor[#,10]&]` will do the job partially.

Comment: `HistogramList` will give you the raw data that makes up the histogram.

Answer (score 3):

## Code

```
dat = Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[50, 20], 1000], 
   0 < # < 100 &];

num = Length@dat;
c = CountsBy[dat, Floor[#, 10] &];
dat = Transpose@
   Block[{tab = Range[0, 90, 10], dat1, dat2}, 
    N@{Transpose@{tab, tab + 10}, tab + 5, dat1 = c /@ tab, 
      dat2 = (c /@ tab)/num, Accumulate@dat1, Accumulate@dat2}];

Column[{
  BarChart[dat[[;; , 3]], 
   AxesLabel -> Evaluate[Style[#, Bold, 20] & /@ {"count", "score"}], 
   ImageSize -> Large, 
   ChartLabels -> (Style[#, 20] & /@ dat[[;; , 2]]), 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],
  Grid[Prepend[
    dat, {"class interval", "class score", "absolute freq", 
     "rel freq", "cum abs freq", "rel cul freq"}], 
   Dividers -> {All, {1 -> Black, 
      2 -> Directive[Thick, Black], -1 -> Black}}, 
   Background -> {{Lighter[Orange, .8], 
      None}, {Lighter[Blue, .8], {Lighter[Green, .9], 
       Lighter[Green, .75]}}}]}, Spacings -> 3]
```

---

## Result

[image: img]

Will this be stylish enough?

The basic idea is to proceed the data first, then adjust those settings in `BarChart` and `Grid`

Comment: yes thank you very much. i think i will be able to modify it...many thansk

Comment: If this can solve your problem, click the checkmark under that number to accept~ :)